# Character "l" replaced with double arrow in mathcal?

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, characters

Very trivial situation: calling in math environment `$\mathcal{Cl}$` replaces the letter "l" with a vertical double arrow. Where is this coming from i.e. with what macro/syntax is this interfering and how can I force the calligraphic "l" to be printed?

Comment: There is no lowercase calligraphic alphabet. Applying `\mathcal` to lowercase letters produces funny output.

Comment: Ah, wow, thanks for pointing that out. I always thought calligraphic lowercase letters would be rather straightforward to draw, but let's draw an arrow instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can consider to use...`\mathcal{C}\ell`..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{C}\ell$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\ell` in bold font (I have used `bm` package) it is better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{C}\bm{\ell}$
\end{document}
```

or with `\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}`, `\mathcal{Cl}` will have a sense

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{Cl}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with a negative space `\!`,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{C\!l}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @Scipham You can see to consider the 2nd or 3th option.

Answer (score 6):

The default `\mathcal` does not have a lowercase alphabet, but you can load other packages that do.  If you can, I’d recommend switching to `unicode-math` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  Others include `newtxmath`, `newpxmath`, `stix2` and `stix`.