# calligraphy \mathcal fonts in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, mathcal

I am facing a problem regarding using `\mathcal` in my beamer presentation and could not make none of the solutions proposed for similar cases work.

Here is the content of my `presentation`.sty file:

```
% --- Fonts ---
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,
amssymb, amsthm, 
eucal, bbold, bm
}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\textnormal{\slshape d}}
\usepackage[italic,eulergreek,symbolmisc]{mathastext}
\usepackage{url}

% Microtypography
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }

% Correct spacing around letters in math
\MTsetmathskips{f}{\thinmuskip}{0mu} 
\MTsetmathskips{y}{\thinmuskip}{0mu}
\MTsetmathskips{p}{\thinmuskip}{0mu}
\MTsetmathskips{l}{0mu}{\thinmuskip}
\MTsetmathskips{j}{\thinmuskip}{\thinmuskip}

% --- Beamer theme ---
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme[]{seagull}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% --- Font sizes and shapes ---
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, series=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\scshape}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\MakeLowercase{\insertframetitle}}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{button}{size=\footnotesize}

% --- Spacing ---
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][left,leftskip=-8pt]
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip3mm}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm}

% --- Color ---
\colorlet{myblack}{black!85!}
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!60!}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=myblack}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=myblack}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myblack}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=mygray}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=mygray} 
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=mygray} 
\setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=mygray}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=mygray}
\setbeamercolor{button}{fg=mygray, bg=white}


% --- Title slide ---
\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle[]{\MakeLowercase{#1}\vspace{-5mm}\\\color{myblack}{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}\vspace{1cm}}}

% Paper information
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\information}{o g g}{%
\author[]{#2%
\IfValueT{#3}{\vspace{5mm}\\#3}%
\IfValueT{#1}{\vspace{5mm}\\\color{mygray}{\footnotesize \url{#1}}}%
}\date[]{}}
```

and here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table},hyperref={pdftex, pdfpagemode=UseNone, hidelinks, pdfdisplaydoctitle=true},usepdftitle=false]{beamer}

\usepackage{presentation}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Presentation Title}}
\newcommand{\pdf}{figures.pdf}

\begin{document}

\title{presentation title}
\information
{first-name last-name}
{place and date}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{This is a math slide}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Function: $\mathcal{g}: \mathcal{X} \mapsto \mathcal{y}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I compile it on overleaf (pdfLatex) and here is what it displays:

[image]

It would be highly appreciated if you could give me some hints to address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a font that has lower case `\mathcal` letters. The default (Computer Modern Sans) for Beamer does not have them. (This would also be mentioned in the compilation logs.)

Relatively few fonts have lower case `\mathcal`. Some previous questions about this include

- [Lowercase \mathscr and \mathcal letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668241/lowercase-mathscr-and-mathcal-letters)
- [Character "l" replaced with double arrow in mathcal?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600104/character-l-replaced-with-double-arrow-in-mathcal)
- [How to get lower case calligraphic font in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348901/how-to-get-lower-case-calligraphic-font-in-math-mode)

and include some suggestions on fonts that do have this range, as well as how to load them.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348901/how-to-get-lower-case-calligraphic-font-in-math-mode#:~:text=2-,Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A) and it worked perfectly.